# I have 4 forms how do I have a submit button for each of them?

Tags: html, forms, submit

I am using the jquery tab control. I have a form in each of them and I want to submit each form independently. I have been googling and reading about forms and submit but the only way I have found so far is by using jquery. I would prefer to use the submit buttons.

Comment: Technically speaking .. A `SUBMISSION` or `SUBMIT` is a `POST` or `GET` to a single page.  If you want each form submitted independently, you will have to use `jQuery` `.post()` or `.get()` from a button that is simply a call to action and not a "real" `SUBMIT` button for the form which would only submit the data for the form it belongs to.  Your best bet is `jQuery` and/or `AJAX` IMHO

Comment: Thank you, I thought when they allowed multiple forms they would have included a way to post them independently.

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html tab forms instead of jQuery's and yes I needed a separate submit button for each form so that it only collected the data from the form it was attached to. You want to create a different form within each div of the tab in question. I found Zurb's Foundation easy to use and they give you code so you only have to tweak it a bit. Here's an example of just one tab using Foundation.

```
 <div class="content" data-slug="panel3" data-section-content="">
      <form>
        <div class="row collapse">
          <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label class="inline">Your Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" id="yourName" placeholder="Jane Smith">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
          <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label class="inline"> Your Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" id="yourEmail" placeholder="jane@smithco.com">
          </div>
        </div>
        <label>What's up?</label>
        <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="radius button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this does not answer your question properly.

Add a `<form>` for each of your tabs.
Add a `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` inside each form.

Make sure that none of your forms are nested inside each other.

You should be able to submit each tab independently.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, I have used jquery to transmit the 2nd to 4th buttons (type=button). I found the 1st (jquery) button did not work so I changed it back to type=submit then all was OK. I am running well behind my deadline so I will not have time to try your answer. When I do I will let you know and if all OK I will tick your answer.

Comment: @JieHart Please mark this answer as accepted if it answered you question.  Or give feedback if it didn't, thanks.